# Strange error on android app

Tags: android, data-retrieval

I do not know what to call this error. My app uses a self written shared preferences class. After a few times of running my app, nothing can be retrieved from my remote server. I'll post my shared preferences and one my my async tasks. There is no error within the logcat when the app does not retrieve anything.

Shared Preferences class:

```
public class SharedPreferences{

    static final String PREF_USER_NAME = "username";
    static final String PREF_USER_ID = "userid";

    static android.content.SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String userName) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, userName);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void setUserId(Context ctx, String userId)
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_USER_ID, userId);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getUserName(Context ctx)
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");
    }

    public static String getUserId(Context ctx)
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_ID, "");
    }

    public static void clearUserName(Context ctx) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.clear(); //clear all stored data
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Item retrieval async task:

```
public class GetEventsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>{

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    MainActivity activityMain;
    List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
    MyDbAdapter db;

    public GetEventsAsyncTask(MainActivity parent)
    {
        activityMain = parent;
    }

     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

//          progressDialog = null;
//          
//           if (progressDialog == null) 
//           {
//                 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activityMain);
//                 progressDialog.setMessage("download events, please wait...");
//                 progressDialog.show();
//                 progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
//                 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
//           }   
        }

          @Override
          protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Boolean error = false;
                try {
                    error = postData(params[0]);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return error;
          }

          protected void onPostExecute(Boolean error){          
                 /* if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                      progressDialog = null;
                  } */
                  if(error==true)
                  {
                      Log.i("GetEvents", "Error at get events");
                      activityMain.errorOccured();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Log.i("onPostExecute:eventlist.count",String.valueOf(eventList.size()));
                      MainActivity.myDB.removeAllEvents();
                      for(int i=0;i<eventList.size();i++)
                      {
                          MainActivity.myDB.insertEventEntry(eventList.get(i));
                      }
                      activityMain.downloadEventsSuccess(eventList);
//                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                  }

          } 

          protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
          }


        public Boolean postData(String user_id) throws JSONException {

            Boolean error = false;
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          // specify the URL you want to post to

            try {
                Log.i("GetEvents", user_id);
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Constants.HOST_NAME+"/"+Constants.SERVICE_NAME+"/api/Event?userId=" + user_id);
                BufferedReader reader;
                StringBuffer sb;
                String line = "";
                String NL="";
                String json;
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
                {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                     sb = new StringBuffer("");
                     line = "";
                     NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + NL);
                    }

                    reader.close();
                    json = sb.toString();

                    Log.i("event json",json);
                    try
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);   

                        for (int i = 0, length = jsonArray.length(); i < length; i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject attribute = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.i("EventsAsync", attribute.toString(i));
                            Event eventObj =  new Event(); 
                            eventObj.setEvent_id(attribute.getString("event_id"));
                            eventObj.setEvent_title(attribute.getString("event_title"));
                            eventObj.setEvent_desc(attribute.getString("event_desc"));
                            eventObj.setStart_date(attribute.getString("start_date"));
                            eventObj.setEnd_date(attribute.getString("end_date"));
                            eventObj.setStart_time(attribute.getString("start_time"));
                            eventObj.setEnd_time(attribute.getString("end_time"));
                            eventObj.setLocation(attribute.getString("location"));
                            eventObj.setPicture_path(attribute.getString("picture_path"));
                            eventObj.setSmall_picture_path(attribute.getString("small_picture_path"));

                            eventList.add(eventObj);
//                          DatabaseUser.openWritable();
//                          DatabaseUser.insertEvent(eventObj);
                            eventObj = null;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        error = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    error = true;
                }


            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                // process execption
                error = true;
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // process execption
                error = true;
            }
            return error;
        }
}
```

Most of the time, the app stops retrieving after 3 times from onStart to onDestroy.

Comment: What exactly issue you are facing?

Comment: After around 3 uses of the app, the app is unable to retrieve any data from the remote server. It will, however, display the system error dialog box. Meaning that it calls the server, however no data is retrieved.

Comment: Try changing 
return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx); 
to 
return ctx.getSharedPreferences(<YOUR APP PACKAGE NAME>, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Looks like doing that worked. Want to answer the question so I can mark it?